# Speedometer as a symbol into awesomebox

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, packages, fontawesome

Actually I'm using [awesomebox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/awesomebox) package to draw blocks around the text. Here there is an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\awesomebox[violet]{2pt}{\faRocket}{violet}{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

Into the guide there is written that: "*The specific aim of this package is to use FontAwesome 5 icons to ease the illustration of these boxes.*"

Is there a font, a specific symbol that can to be inserted (instead of the `fontawesome5` package symbols) to have three different types of speedometer without or with text like this [image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUgOqE_svkAhXBYVAKHb06DSYQjhx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fit.dreamstime.com%2Fscala-del-tachimetro-dell-illustrazione-di-vettore-da-verde-rosso-con-la-freccia-e-testo-basso-medio-ed-alto-image134690900&psig=AOvVaw1k8ZN1RXvMuzsr_G0Na4FU&ust=1568401498966472)?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple pic with the "speed" as parameter may do.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/speedometer/.style={code={
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {green!70!black/low,orange/medium,red/high}
  {\fill[fill=\X] (240-\Z*60:4) arc(240-\Z*60:180-\Z*60:4) -- 
    (180-\Z*60:3) arc(180-\Z*60:240-\Z*60:3) -- cycle;
   \path [decorate, decoration={text along path,
   text={|\color{white}\Huge\sffamily\bfseries|\Y}, text align=center}] 
    (240-\Z*60:3.2) arc(240-\Z*60:180-\Z*60:3.25);}
   \fill (180-#1+8:0.3) arc (180-#1+8:180-#1+344:0.3) -- (180-#1-0.5:3.25)
   -- (180-#1+0.5:3.25) --  cycle;
  }}]
  \path (0,0) pic{speedometer=45}
  (0,-5) pic{speedometer=80}
  (0,-10) pic{speedometer=160};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably more fancy version thereof is obtained when making the color transitions smooth. To this end we need to rotate and flip the color wheel that comes with the `shadings` library. This can be done using `transform canvas`, which has some side-effect, which is why the results get stored in a `\savebox` and then reused.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\newsavebox\ColorWheelRotated
\sbox\ColorWheelRotated{\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (180:4) arc(180:0:4) -- (3,0) arc(0:180:3);
    \shade[shading=color wheel,transform canvas={
    rotate=-65,xscale=-1}] (0,0) circle [radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/speedometer/.style={code={
 \path (0,0) node[above,inner sep=0pt] {\usebox\ColorWheelRotated};
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {green!70!black/low,orange/medium,red/high}
  {
   \path [decorate, decoration={text along path,
   text={|\color{white}\Huge\sffamily\bfseries|\Y}, text align=center}] 
    (240-\Z*60:3.2) arc(240-\Z*60:180-\Z*60:3.25);}
   \fill (180-#1+8:0.3) arc (180-#1+8:180-#1+344:0.3) -- (180-#1-0.5:3.25)
   -- (180-#1+0.5:3.25) --  cycle;
  }}]
  \path (0,0) pic{speedometer=45}
  (0,-5) pic{speedometer=80}
  (0,-10) pic{speedometer=160};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to make this symbols you may want to kick out the texts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/speedometer/.style={code={
 \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {green!70!black/low,orange/medium,red/high}
  {\fill[fill=\X] (240-\Z*60:4) arc(240-\Z*60:180-\Z*60:4) -- 
    (180-\Z*60:3) arc(180-\Z*60:240-\Z*60:3) -- cycle;}
   \fill (180-#1+8:0.3) arc (180-#1+8:180-#1+344:0.3) -- (180-#1-0.5:3.25)
   -- (180-#1+0.5:3.25) --  cycle;
  }}}
\newsavebox\LowSpeed  
\newsavebox\MediumSpeed  
\newsavebox\HighSpeed  
\sbox\LowSpeed{\scalebox{0.1}{\tikz{\pic{speedometer=45};}}}
\sbox\MediumSpeed{\scalebox{0.1}{\tikz{\pic{speedometer=90};}}}
\sbox\HighSpeed{\scalebox{0.1}{\tikz{\pic{speedometer=135};}}}
\begin{document}
\awesomebox[violet]{2pt}{\usebox\LowSpeed}{violet}{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But can I put one of the three speedometer instead of `\faRocket`?

Comment: @Sebastiano Whether or not this will yield a useful **symbol** that has a size that is comparable to an ordinary character I do not know because of the texts that you embed. Once you scale it down, the texts will be pretty much unreadable. If you leave the texts "low" etc. out this may become useful symbols. I added a proposal.

Comment: This is very nice, many thanks! Do you know if it is possile to specify the colors in the example with shading? At the moment, the colors you specify with `green!70!black/low,orange/medium,red/high` do not have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

I have found on this [link](https://latexdraw.com/how-to-write-a-text-along-path-using-tikz-speedometer-case/) a very nice speedometer too. I made a few small changes to associate it with my initial question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
% Static part
\draw[draw=white,fill=red,thick] (0:2) -- (0:3.5) arc(0:45:3.5) -- (45:2) arc(45:0:2) -- cycle ;
\draw[draw=white,fill=red!30,thick] (90:2cm)-- (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5) -- (45:2cm) arc (45:90:2);
\draw[draw=white,fill=orange!30,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5) -- (90:2cm) arc (90:135:2);
\draw[draw=white,fill=yellow!20,thick] (135:2cm)-- (135:3.5cm) arc (135:180:3.5) -- (180:2cm) arc (180:135:2);


%Labels
\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={LOW},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (180:3.5cm) arc (180:135:3.5); 

\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={MEDIUM},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (135:3.5cm) arc (135:90:3.5);

\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={HIGH},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (90:3.5cm) arc (90:45:3.5);

\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={CRITICAL},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (45:3.5cm) arc (45:0:3.5);


% Speedometer needle
\fill[black!70,rotate=40] (0,0.2)--(0:2.75) -- (0,-0.2)--cycle;
\fill [black!70](0,0) circle (0.4cm);
\fill [white](0,0) circle (0.15cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wooo I like the colours. Good answer!! I wish you a good weekend start.

Comment: @manooooh LOL :-) the answer is not mine with all my sincerity. There is also the link. :) thank you very much.