# How can I draw the four strokes of spark-ignition engine?

Tags: tikz-pgf, engineering

[image: Four Strokes of Heat Engine]

I want to draw four strokes of a spark-ignition engine by using Tikz package but I don't know to start. Anyone here help me, please. Thanks

Comment: You have to start learning how to create a line first.

Comment: Welcome. It is conceptually straightforward but tedious to create this. You may have a look e.g. at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/transmission-electron-microscope/ to get an idea of "how to start".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a start. It is a `pic` which has keys for all (?) variable parameters. You can adjust these parameters to produce the various steps. Of course one may make things fancier.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,shapes.symbols}
\newif\ifspark
\tikzset{tangent of circles/.style args={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464143/194703
    at #1 and #2 with radii #3 and #4}{insert path={%
    let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)*1pt/1cm},
    \n3={atan2(#4-#3,\n2)}
     in ($(#1)+(\n3+\n1+90:#3)$) coordinate(aux1) -- 
     ($(#2)+(\n3+\n1+90:#4)$) coordinate(aux2)}},
     pics/engine/.style={code={
  \tikzset{engine/.cd,#1}
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (0,0) -- (-0.8,-0.4) coordinate[pos=0.4] (p1)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p2) |- (-1,-3)[rounded corners=1mm] |- (-1.2,0) [sharp corners]
  -- (-1.2,0.7) coordinate[pos=0.2] (p3)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p4) -- (-0.9,0.85) -- (-0.6,0.7) -- (0,0.4) -- (0.6,0.7)
  -- (0.9,0.85)-- (1.2,0.7) -- (1.2,0)coordinate[pos=0.2] (p6)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p5) {[rounded corners=1mm] -- (1,0)}
  [sharp corners] -- (1,-3)
  -| (0.8,-0.4) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.2] (p8)
  coordinate[pos=0.6] (p7);
  \draw[engine/left exhaust] (p1) to[bend right=18] (p4) -- (p3) to[bend left=18] (p2) -- cycle;
  \draw[engine/right exhaust] (p7) to[bend left=18] (p6) -- (p5) to[bend right=18] (p8) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,-4) circle[radius=5mm];
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pistonpos}{-4+0.4*sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle})
  +sqrt(1.5*1.5-pow(0.4*cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle}),2))}
  \path (0,-4) + (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle}:0.4) coordinate (p9)
   (0,\pistonpos) coordinate (p10);
  \draw[fill=gray!15] (p9) circle [radius=2mm] -- (p10) circle [radius=1mm];
  \path[tangent of circles={at p10 and p9 with radii 0.1 and 0.2}]
  (aux1) coordinate (aux3) (aux2) coordinate (aux4); 
  \path[tangent of circles={at p9 and p10 with radii 0.2 and 0.1}];
  \path[fill=gray!15] (aux1) -- (aux2) -- (aux3) -- (aux4);
  \draw  (aux1) -- (aux2)  (aux3) -- (aux4);
  \path[fill=gray!45] (p9) circle [radius=1.2mm];
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (-0.8,\pistonpos)   rectangle ++ (1.6,1);
   \draw[left color=gray!60,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!10] (-0.8,\pistonpos) 
  rectangle ++ (2,1);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[left color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/interior color}!80,
  right color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/interior color}!50,
  middle color=white] 
  (-0.8,\pistonpos+1) --  (-0.8,-0.4)  -- (0,0)--  (0.8,-0.4) |- cycle;
  \draw[thin,fill=gray!30] (-0.42,-0.5) 
   ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/left valve}) 
   -- ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++ ({atan(1/2)}:0.1)
   -- ++ ({-90+atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++({atan(1/2)}:0.3)
   -- ++ ({-90+atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- ++({atan(1/2)+180}:0.7)
   -- ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[thin,fill=gray!30] (0.42,-0.5) 
   ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/right valve}) 
   -- ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++ ({180-atan(1/2)}:0.1)
   -- ++ ({-90-atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++({180-atan(1/2)}:0.3)
   -- ++ ({-90-atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- ++({-atan(1/2)}:0.7)
   -- ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[left color=gray!60,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!10]
   (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (0.1,1);   
  \ifspark
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (-1.8,-0.2) rectangle (1.8,\pistonpos+1.1);
   \path (0,-0.2) node[starburst, inner color=yellow, outer color=red,minimum size=1cm]{};
  \end{scope}
  \fi 
 }},engine/.cd,left valve/.initial=1,right valve/.initial=1,
 left exhaust/.style={fill=gray!50},
 right exhaust/.style={fill=gray!50},
 rod angle/.initial=30,interior color/.initial=white,
 spark/.is if=spark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[] 
 \path (0,0) pic{engine={left valve=0,rod angle=-40,
  left exhaust/.style={fill=gray!10}}}
 (3.2,0) pic{engine={rod angle=-170,interior color=yellow}}
 (6.4,0) pic{engine={rod angle=105,interior color=orange,spark}}
 (9.6,0) pic{engine={rod angle=-80,interior color=red}}
 (12.8,0) pic{engine={right valve=0,rod angle=-170,interior color=purple,
    right exhaust/.style={fill=purple!30}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is a completely unrealistic (I am a cyclist! ;-) animation whose only purpose is to illustrate how the parameters work. Thanks for all the feedback!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,shapes.symbols}
\newif\ifspark
\tikzset{tangent of circles/.style args={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464143/194703
    at #1 and #2 with radii #3 and #4}{insert path={%
    let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)*1pt/1cm},
    \n3={atan2(#4-#3,\n2)}
     in ($(#1)+(\n3+\n1+90:#3)$) coordinate(aux1) -- 
     ($(#2)+(\n3+\n1+90:#4)$) coordinate(aux2)}},
     pics/engine/.style={code={
  \tikzset{engine/.cd,#1}
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (0,0) -- (-0.8,-0.4) coordinate[pos=0.4] (p1)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p2) |- (-1,-3)[rounded corners=1mm] |- (-1.2,0) [sharp corners]
  -- (-1.2,0.7) coordinate[pos=0.2] (p3)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p4) -- (-0.9,0.85) -- (-0.6,0.7) -- (0,0.4) -- (0.6,0.7)
  -- (0.9,0.85)-- (1.2,0.7) -- (1.2,0)coordinate[pos=0.2] (p6)
  coordinate[pos=0.8] (p5) {[rounded corners=1mm] -- (1,0)}
  [sharp corners] -- (1,-3)
  -| (0.8,-0.4) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.2] (p8)
  coordinate[pos=0.6] (p7);
  \draw[engine/left exhaust] (p1) to[bend right=18] (p4) -- (p3) to[bend left=18] (p2) -- cycle;
  \draw[engine/right exhaust] (p7) to[bend left=18] (p6) -- (p5) to[bend right=18] (p8) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!50] (0,-4) circle[radius=5mm];
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pistonpos}{-4+0.4*sin(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle})
  +sqrt(1.5*1.5-pow(0.4*cos(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle}),2))}
  \path (0,-4) + (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/rod angle}:0.4) coordinate (p9)
   (0,\pistonpos) coordinate (p10);
  \draw[fill=gray!15] (p9) circle [radius=2mm] -- (p10) circle [radius=1mm];
  \path[tangent of circles={at p10 and p9 with radii 0.1 and 0.2}]
  (aux1) coordinate (aux3) (aux2) coordinate (aux4); 
  \path[tangent of circles={at p9 and p10 with radii 0.2 and 0.1}];
  \path[fill=gray!15] (aux1) -- (aux2) -- (aux3) -- (aux4);
  \draw  (aux1) -- (aux2)  (aux3) -- (aux4);
  \path[fill=gray!45] (p9) circle [radius=1.2mm];
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (-0.8,\pistonpos)   rectangle ++ (1.6,1);
   \draw[left color=gray!60,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!10] (-0.8,\pistonpos) 
  rectangle ++ (2,1);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[left color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/interior color}!80,
  right color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/interior color}!50,
  middle color=white] 
  (-0.8,\pistonpos+1) --  (-0.8,-0.4)  -- (0,0)--  (0.8,-0.4) |- cycle;
  \draw[thin,fill=gray!30] (-0.42,-0.5) 
   ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/left valve}) 
   -- ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++ ({atan(1/2)}:0.1)
   -- ++ ({-90+atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++({atan(1/2)}:0.3)
   -- ++ ({-90+atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- ++({atan(1/2)+180}:0.7)
   -- ++ ({90+atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[thin,fill=gray!30] (0.42,-0.5) 
   ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/engine/right valve}) 
   -- ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++ ({180-atan(1/2)}:0.1)
   -- ++ ({-90-atan(1/2)}:1.9) -- ++({180-atan(1/2)}:0.3)
   -- ++ ({-90-atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- ++({-atan(1/2)}:0.7)
   -- ++ ({90-atan(1/2)}:0.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[left color=gray!60,right color=gray!50,middle color=gray!10]
   (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (0.1,1);   
  \ifspark
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (-1.8,-0.2) rectangle (1.8,\pistonpos+1.1);
   \path (0,-0.2) node[starburst, inner color=yellow, outer color=red,minimum size=1cm]{};
  \end{scope}
  \fi 
 }},engine/.cd,left valve/.initial=1,right valve/.initial=1,
 left exhaust/.style={fill=gray!50},
 right exhaust/.style={fill=gray!50},
 rod angle/.initial=30,interior color/.initial=white,
 spark/.is if=spark}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,20,...,700}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\lv}{ifthenelse(\X<=90||\X>=630,min(1-cos(\X),1),1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\li}{100*\lv}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rv}{ifthenelse(\X>360,min(1+cos(\X),1),1)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ri}{50*(1-\rv)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cA}{100*max(-sin(\X/2),0)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cB}{100*max(sin(\X/2),0)}
\colorlet{myinterior}{purple!\cA!red!\cB!orange}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-1.6,-5) rectangle (1.6,2); 
 \ifnum\X=280
  \path (0,0) pic{engine={left valve=\lv,right valve=\rv,rod angle=-\X,
   left exhaust/.style={fill=gray!\li},right exhaust/.style={fill=purple!\ri!gray},
   interior color=myinterior,spark}};
 \else
  \path (0,0) pic{engine={left valve=\lv,right valve=\rv,rod angle=-\X,
   left exhaust/.style={fill=gray!\li},right exhaust/.style={fill=purple!\ri!gray},
   interior color=myinterior}};
 \fi 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this guide. I'm really appreciate your help.

Comment: The legend continues. (+1).

Comment: I did it already and it works nicely

Comment: Very nice work but the spark append when both holes are closed, aren't they?

Comment: @Tarass Thanks! I tried to improve it but I am sure it is still inaccurate.

Comment: Really nice suggestion...

Comment: This is a truly ridiculous answer for a question that got put on hold in the end.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'd suggest `\pgfmathsetmacro{\lv}{ifthenelse(\X<=90||\X>=630,min(1-cos(\X),1),1)}` and `\pgfmathsetmacro{\rv}{ifthenelse(\X>360,min(1+cos(\X),1),1)}` for the valves and test `\ifnum\X=280` for the spark :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks!

Comment: Now @CarLaTeX's car can have a proper engine ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The accessories start to accumulate: she also has as ["speed-o-meter"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508087/194703) at her disposal.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it does not work properly
https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d827a6622d8d20001d4733a

Comment: @SomonMel Sorry, I do not use overleaf. All I can say is that what I am showing here are the results of the compilations of the above codes on an updated TeXLive installation with `pdflatex`. Unfortunately, it is a recurring problem that overleaf does not update their packages, nor do they make it easy to debug the issue. In any case, if these codes do not work on overleaf, this is something their support should be able to fix. I can't since I do not use overleaf.